# Checking if an object has a key with a type predicate

Tags: typescript

I have a situation that I think needs a type predicate or "narrowing"?

```
const obj1 = { foo: 123 }
const obj2 = { bar: 456 }

type ObjKey = keyof typeof obj1 | keyof typeof obj2
function getVal(key: ObjKey) {
  return key in obj1 ? obj1[key] : obj2[key]
}
```

That doesn't work, do I put a "type guard" on a checking function?  Not sure how to write that example:

```
function objHasKey(obj: object, key: string) {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
}
function getVal(key: ObjKey) {
  return objHasKey(obj1, key) ? obj1[key] : obj2[key]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can write a user-defined type guard like this:

```
function objHasKey<T>(obj: T, key: PropertyKey): key is keyof T {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
}
```

Note that `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)` is almost always preferable to `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` because if you don't know what properties an object has, then you don't know for sure that it inherits the `hasOwnProperty` property from `Object.prototype`. If you write `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`, then the compiler will actually complain that `T` doesn't have a `hasOwnProperty` method, which is kind of accurate for this reason.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAjDAvDA3jAZiEAXDMgEwDMMAvgLABQoksCiJ6WM8AhgE5EAsAVgBsVOnSgBPAA4BTGAHkkAaRkS2Aa1UgcMSbO1wkqAD4xNEg3pkHmJOjgCuYYFACW4Q4gASnCCokAPAAqAHwAFMxEQQA0ZqpEAArcILLckv4AlETmMK4QcRY6QVh0MDDcMlAO3GAKSDIuAHRSyVAgVo0AFr7yAO5gSSkyaRKNwJwANhMRSLHmGQDcdDS0js5uHgDmlQBqk2HmRIqImSW0ZRVVNZ4+fqozKHOqGTAA-J7IANrmALowRLZvqofss6EA)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for with "key is keyof T" thank you!  Also thanks for the tip on using Object for hasOwnProperty.