# Narrowing that an object has an arbitrary field of a certain type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write some data validation helpers that assure the TypeScript compiler that

```
function process(data: unknown) {
  assert(data instanceof Object);

  // need a helper for this line
  assert(  hasSubobject(data, 'some_field')  );

  // so that this line doesn't complain about `some_field` not existing
  assert(typeof data.some_field === 'string');

  // …
}
```

I know I could just hardcode this as `'some_field' in data && data.some_field instanceof Object` inline and even figured out that I could hardcode a helper like:

```
function hasHardcodedSubobject(data: object): data is {hardcodedField: object} {
  return (
    "hardcodedField" in data &&
    data.hardcodedField instanceof Object
  );
}
```

but I am unsure of how to convert this to something more dynamic, like:

```
function hasSubobject(data: object, key: string): data is {[key]: object} {
  return (
    key in data &&
    data[key] instanceof Object
  );
}
```

This is somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68959950/179583 and in that case the solution **could** just use "key" as a variable via `key is keyof T` but for some reason I *can't* use it my way. It gives:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)

even though with `key: string` its type is a <del>literal</del> (update: I'm probably mixing up "literal" vs. "primitive"!) type, i.e. `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need generic types on your `hasSubobject` function. One to capture the object type you are passing in, and another for the key your validating.

```
function hasSubobject<T extends object, K extends string>(
  data: T,
  key: K
): data is T & { [key in K]: object } {
  return (
    key in data &&
    data[key as unknown as keyof T] instanceof Object
  );
}
```

Here `T` is the object type being validated, and `K` os the key name that will be narrowed.

The return value is then a type predicate where `T` is intersected with an object type where the property `K` is locked down to be an `object` type.

This `data[key as unknown as keyof T]` is unfortunate, but Typescript can't seem to track that `key` is a keyof `T`, but it definitely is due to the `key in data` check. So we can override it with the forceful assertion here.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXygGdCQYMAKWAcwC54AjHHCEKVASjqJLMIJioAoQSnTY88AA4wcYEMXLAoGKHTQBrVDgDuHeAG9B8AsVIUlK+FlSEV6EDkTwA8vQBW4DOwDcw4wHp-eFQQEGACeAALEAhJUiQcGHgMSKw+CGsQIxMeCmNIogBlZEZ3T0VlKAAaeAByQhwAWxAAfUQsGOBa9mMfP3hA+AbkgowRtPgMkPhgHHlUWrGwJsloawJGZDGAAwbmto6IYG3gnDGQAA807FQhY24zcgwATzjHGcqAOj3W9s74AC8QLqthg1io3V82UGgDICQQAX2EwlEmFw+AKhGKpQ8mAAPAAVeCXDAgVDAPg4MqYGoAaSJFxJZL4oPBAD5yNkLKp4Piqtl1CBnnQaYJOB9LBNCQAyAzwADaAueVnwNIAunRKTixvCDNk4BhkDB8BzjMZFcrxVB4FKpdljFyFYKTPANFpdM7Fe98arlbY2HJ3q4tdk+vCgA)

Comment: Ah, thanks! This is actually somewhat similar to a half-solution I was starting to work out (see the now-alternate answer I just accidentally cross-posted :-) and maybe by combining the two I could get rid of the extra `T` need — afaict the common ground is to not rely on `key` as a variable but rather go about it by way of a generically literal `type K = "…";` that in practice does just represent one particular string.

Comment: [deleted earlier incorrect comment about the purpose of the generic `T` — I see now it's needed **both** for the return type annotation *and* your `data[key]` workaround rather than just the latter.]

Answer (score 0):

By brushing off some [code I found](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29259#issuecomment-451458422) in an older TypeScript thread, I was able to make something that **almost** works:

```
type withKey<K extends PropertyKey> = {
  [k in K]: object
}

function hasSubObject<K extends PropertyKey>(data: object, key: K): data is withKey<K> {
  return (
    key in data &&
    // @ts-expect-error ts(2536)
    data[key] instanceof Object
  );
}
```

I say "almost" because I have to tell the compiler to ignore it being upset about `data[key]` even after I check `key in data`, so this probably isn't an ideal solution :-/